# How to change my language of DataTable?

Tags: datatable

I have below Function that my Table information  change to an DataTable.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable(
                {
                   
                        "sProcessing":   "درحال پردازش...",
                        "sLengthMenu":   "نمایش محتویات _MENU_",
                        "sZeroRecords":  "موردی یافت نشد",
                        "sInfo":         "نمایش _START_ تا _END_ از مجموع _TOTAL_ مورد",
                        "sInfoEmpty":    "تهی",
                        "sInfoFiltered": "(فیلتر شده از مجموع _MAX_ مورد)",
                        "sInfoPostFix":  "",
                        "sSearch":       "جستجو:",
                        "sUrl":          "",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst":    "ابتدا",
                            "sPrevious": "قبلی",
                            "sNext":     "بعدی",
                            "sLast":     "انتها"
                        }
                    
                }


                );

            

        });
    </script>
```

I want change my language of DataTable to Persian But not working.

Comment: You forget to sign the literal to the `language` property, it shouldf be `language:  {  "sProcessing": ....` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/781/**